# How to enter a multiline string representing JSON into Visual Studio

Tags: c#, json, string, visual-studio

If I enter this into `Visual Studio` editor, it is a mess and it doesn't work as `s` is spread over `multiple lines` in the Editor and contains embedded `"` characters.

```
// This is my json string
string s = "
{
    "label": "MyLabel",
    "values": {
      "Key1": "Value1",
      "Key2": "Value2",
      "Key2": "Value3",
    }
}";
```

How do I annotate this with `@` and `\` so that is is a `edit-time` `JSON` `string` ?

Comment: By the way this has nothing to do with JSON.  Think about it.  How would you parse `string s = " { "label": "MyLabel" };`.  Literal strings start and end with a double quote, so what that looks like to the compiler is `string s = " { "` followed by and unexpected (and unquoted) `label` followed by an unexpected literal string (`": "`) followed by an unexpected and unquoted `MyLabel` followed by a dangling start of a string (with no closing quote): (`" };`).  It's unparsable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a verbatim string using `@""` and replace " with ""

Like this:

```
// This is my json string
string s = @"
{
    ""label"": ""MyLabel"",
        ""values"": {
        ""Key1"": ""Value1"",
        ""Key2"": ""Value2"",
        ""Key2"": ""Value3"",
    }
}
            ";
```